# How to convert SID to String in .net

Tags: c#, .net

I would like to convert the SID's System.Byte[] type to a String.

My code:

```
string path = "LDAP://DC=abc,DC=contoso,DC=com";
DirectoryEntry entry = new DirectoryEntry(path);
DirectorySearcher mySearcher = new DirectorySearcher(entry);

mySearcher.Filter = "(&(objectClass=user)(samaccountname=user1))";
results = mySearcher.FindAll();
foreach (SearchResult searchResult in results)
{
    Console.WriteLine(searchResult.Properties["ObjectSID"][0].ToString());
}
```

I tried with this but it gets the values from the domain I'm currently logged in, and i need from a given domain.

```
System.Security.Principal.NTAccount(user1)
    .Translate([System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier]).value
```

Answer (score 62, accepted):

Take a look at the [SecurityIdentifier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.principal.securityidentifier.aspx) class.  You can then do simple things like,

```
var sidInBytes = (byte[]) *somestuff*
var sid = new SecurityIdentifier(sidInBytes, 0);
// This gives you what you want
sid.ToString();
```

Answer (score 2):

After load the property in directoryEntry ....

```
var usrId = (byte[])directoryEntry.Properties["objectSid"][0];
var objectID = (new SecurityIdentifier(usrId,0)).ToString();
```

Answer (score 1):

This is what I've done, after some reading it seemed safer to store the value in oct.

If you don't know which servers is on the other side.

The code below shows how to do it to get your desired result:

```
private static string ExtractSinglePropertyValueFromByteArray(object value)
{
    //all if checks etc has been omitted
    string propertyValue = string.Empty;
    var bytes = (byte[])value;
    var propertyValueOct = BuildOctString(bytes); // 010500....etc
    var propertyValueSec = BuildSecString(bytes); // S-1-5-...etc
    propertyValue = propertyValueSec;
    return propertyValue;
}

private static string BuildSecString(byte[] bytes)
{
    return new SecurityIdentifier(bytes,0).Value.ToString();
}

private static string BuildOctString(byte[] bytes)
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < bytes.Length; i++)
    {
        sb.Append(bytes[i].ToString("X2"));
    }
    return sb.ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

SecurityIdentifier isn't available under .Net Core, but as long as you just want the string representation (aka Security Descriptor Definition Language or SDDL string), it's not to hard to construct.

Basically there is a version number (1 byte), a section count (1 byte), an identifying authority (6 bytes), and 1 to 5 subauthorites (4 bytes each).

I created a [github repo, with unit test](https://github.com/jrmoreno1/ConvertSIDByteArayToSIDStirng/) based upon a [CodeProject article](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/303160/Converting-a-SID-in-Array-of-bytes-to-String-versi), and added a transformer based upon a [gist by Miro Mannino](https://gist.github.com/miromannino/04be6a64ea0b5f4d4254bb321e09d628) after translating it to VB. Translating to c# is left as an exercise for the reader...

```vb
    ''' Cribbed from https://gist.github.com/miromannino/04be6a64ea0b5f4d4254bb321e09d628
    ''' where the license was (per a comment from miro):
    ''' The License is: Do Whatever You Want With It 2.0
    ''' aka I don't care, I hope it helps you!
    Private Shared Function GetSid(byteCollection As IEnumerable(Of Byte)) As String

        ' sid[0] is the Revision, we allow only version 1, because it's the
        ' only version that exists right now.
        If byteCollection(0) <> 1 Then Throw New ArgumentOutOfRangeException("SID (bytes(0)) revision must be 1")

        Dim stringSidBuilder = New StringBuilder("S-1-")

        ' The next byte specifies the numbers of sub authorities
        ' (number of dashes minus two), should be 5 or less, but not enforcing that
        Dim subAuthorityCount = byteCollection(1)

        ' IdentifierAuthority (6 bytes starting from the second) (big endian)
        Dim identifierAuthority As Long = 0

        Dim offset = 2
        Dim size = 6
        Dim i As Integer

        For i = 0 To size - 1
            identifierAuthority = identifierAuthority Or CLng(byteCollection(offset + i)) << 8 * (size - 1 - i)
        Next

        stringSidBuilder.Append(identifierAuthority.ToString())

        ' Iterate all the SubAuthority (little-endian)
        offset = 8
        size = 4 ' 32-bits (4 bytes) for each SubAuthority
        i = 0
        While i < subAuthorityCount
            Dim subAuthority As Long = 0

            For j = 0 To size - 1
                ' the below "Or" is a logical Or not a boolean operator
                subAuthority = subAuthority Or CLng(byteCollection(offset + j)) << 8 * j
            Next
            stringSidBuilder.Append("-").Append(subAuthority)
            i += 1
            offset += size
        End While

        Return stringSidBuilder.ToString()
    End Function
```