# Active Directory Search displaying properties GUID and SID returns system.Byte[] instead of Actual Values

Tags: c#

This code produces the following output:

```
my email address,
System.Byte[], this should be SID
System.Byte[], this should be GUID
my name,
First Name,
last Name,
Middle Initial
```

Code:

```
Console.WriteLine(((byte)de.Properties["objectSid"].Value.ToString());
```

I attempted to cast the above line. I get an error

> Cannot convert type string to byte

```
string ObjGuid = BitConverter.ToString(de.Properties["objectguid"].Value);
```

I attempted the above line of code same response

```
((byte)de.Properties["ObjectGUID"]).Value.ToString();
```

> Cannot convert type SystemDirectoryServices.PropertyValueCollection to byte

```
byte one = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(de.Properties["ObjectGUID"]));
```

> Cannot convert type SystemDirectoryServices.PropertyValueCollection to byte

These are the items that I have attempted. `Console.WriteLine` requires a string.

The problem that I see is that I am getting a list of items.

From this list, I am getting the underlying properties.

I am only collecting a few items of the collection of properties.

I am searching inside the underlying collection and I am attempting to convert
that item to a string

I think this is a basic conversion from byte to string. I might have an issue with searching and manipulating an object hierarchy.

Can someone help me with this concept?

```
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Security.Principal;
using System.Threading;
using System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement;
using System.DirectoryServices;
using System.IO;
using System.Data;
using System.Management.Automation;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;

//using System.DirectoryServices;
namespace TestRole
{
  class Program
  {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //Requires Add References to using System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement;
        // and using System.DirectoryServices;


        PrincipalContext ctx = new 
               PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain,Environment.UserDomainName);
        UserPrincipal user = new UserPrincipal(ctx);

        user.EmailAddress = "MyEmail@com";

        PrincipalSearcher ps = new PrincipalSearcher();
        ps.QueryFilter = user;
        PrincipalSearchResult<Principal> results = ps.FindAll();
        Principal pc = results.ToList()[0];
        DirectoryEntry de = (DirectoryEntry)pc.GetUnderlyingObject();

        Console.WriteLine(de.Properties["mail"].Value.ToString());

      //old code
        ////Console.WriteLine(de.Properties["Sid"].Value.ToString());
        //Console.WriteLine(de.Properties["objectSid"].Value.ToString());
        //Console.WriteLine(de.Properties["objectGUID"].Value.ToString());
        //This code does the job
            var sid = new 
             SecurityIdentifier((byte[])de.Properties["objectSid"].Value, 0);
               Console.WriteLine(sid);
            var guid = new Guid((Byte[])de.Properties["objectGUID"].Value);
               Console.WriteLine(guid.ToString());


        Console.WriteLine(de.Properties["Name"].Value.ToString());
        Console.WriteLine(de.Properties["givenname"].Value.ToString());
        Console.WriteLine(de.Properties["sn"].Value.ToString());
        Console.WriteLine(de.Properties["initials"].Value.ToString());


        Console.WriteLine(Environment.UserDomainName);


        //Console.WriteLine(de.Properties["StructuralObjectClass"].Value.ToString());

       }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you try to cast your object to `byte` while you specify that it returns `byte[]`? You convert object (presumably, either string or byte array) to string and then cast this string to a `byte` which will produce an error for sure. Make sure that you do your operations in correct order. Try to make them step by step, one operation per line, instead of putting it all in the same line - it can make debugging more difficult.

Comment: What does `de.Properties["objectSid"].Value` return? If its byte[], why trying to cast it to byte? If it is byte[] or a GUID string, cast to byte[] or string and use the appropriate GUID constructor: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.guid.-ctor?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Guid__ctor_System_Byte___

Comment: Hi All, I thought I was clear. I am trying to get the value in AD for the Sid and Guid. Both types are returning System.Byte[] instead of value. I was attempting to convert system.byte[] to array. Can you provide an example? 
            Byte[] guidx = de.Properties["objectGUID"].Value as Byte[];
            string two = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(guidx);
            Console.WriteLine(two); I attempted the above I get garabage.

Answer (score 1):

You need to check the type of the returned values before using or converting them. The return type of `de.Properties["anyPropHere"].Value` is `object`, because it will return different types, depending on the queried property.

If you want to get the `objectSid` as string you have to convert the returned bytes using the `SecurityIdentifier`, as described in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11580128/how-to-convert-sid-to-string-in-net)

```
byte[] sid = (byte[])de.Properties["objectSid"].Value;
string sidStr = (new SecurityIdentifier((byte[])sid, 0)).ToString();
```

Comment: Hi this  solution works great for the sid but the guid Using the above post I did the following   var sid = new SecurityIdentifier((byte[])de.Properties["objectSid"].Value, 0);
            Console.WriteLine(sid);

Comment: Between the three of you I was able to piece the answer together:       var guid = new Guid((Byte[])de.Properties["objectGUID"].Value);
     Console.WriteLine(guid.ToString()); this works for the GUID I will edit the initial question not sure how to say the answer. i had to use all three post for the answer