# C# Decoding Active Directory SID third digit being decoded incorrectly. All other's correct

Tags: c#, active-directory, sid

I retrieve an `objectsid` value from Active Directory.  It comes as a base64 encoded string.

I have the following function (below) to decode this into an actual SID text string.

The following function works just fine in all cases **except a few**.

When examined in the Active Directory Attribute Editor, a SID of "S-1-**5**-21-3477787073-812361429-1014394821" is being returned instead as "S-1-**4**-21-3477787073-812361429-1014394821".  The third digit is off by one.

Likewise, a SID of "S-1-**5**-32-573" is being returned as "S-1-**2**-32-573", and again, the third digit is short by 3.

I've debugged it enough to figure out that it is the length of the byte[] array that is different, and I think is the cause of this error.

When the byte array is 28 bits, it decodes correctly.  If it is shorter than 28 bits, the third SID digit is off directly relative to how much shorter the byte[] array is.

I think there is something about the for() loop condition `i < bytes[7]`, even though `byte[7]` seems to always be `5` in all cases (at least the ones that I have breakpointed).

Or possibly the BitConverter's second parameter `(8 + (i * 4))`.  If `byte[7]` is always 5, then (5*4) + 8 = 28.  And when the byte array is 28 bits, the return value is always correct.  It is when the byte[] array is less than 28 bits that the return value is wrong.

I did not write this function (found on another stack overflow question answer), so I do not really understand what it is doing beyond what I've described here.  I did add the code comments.

```
public static string Base64DecodeSID(string data) {

if (data == "") {
    return "";
}

byte[] bytes = Convert.FromBase64String(data);

try {

    string sid = "S-" + bytes[0].ToString();                                        // Add SID revision.

    if (bytes[6] != 0 || bytes[5] != 0) {                                           // SID authority

        sid += ("-" +
            String.Format(                                                          // Left 0-pad hex
                "0x{0:2x}{1:2x}{2:2x}{3:2x}{4:2x}{5:2x}",                           // values to 2 places.
                bytes[1], bytes[2], bytes[3], bytes[4], bytes[5], bytes[6]
            )
        );

    } else {
        sid += ("-" + (bytes[1] + (bytes[2] << 8) + (bytes[3] << 16) + (bytes[4] << 24)).ToString());
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < bytes[7]; i++) {                                            // Sub-Authority...
        sid += ("-" + BitConverter.ToUInt32(bytes, 8 + (i * 4)).ToString()); 
        
    }

    return sid;

}
```

(I excluded the catch() for brevity)

Example

Base64: `"AQQAAAAAAAUVAAAAwdFKz9WmazDFb3Y8"`

Decoded byte[] array:

```
[00] 1
[01] 4
[02] 0
[03] 0
[04] 0
[05] 0
[06] 0
[07] 5
[08] 21
[09] 0
[10] 0
[11] 0
[12] 193
[13] 209
[14] 74
[15] 207
[16] 213
[17] 166
[18] 107
[19] 48
[20] 197
[21] 111
[22] 118
[23] 60
```

Expected return value:  "S-1-**5**-21-3477787073-812361429-1014394821"

Actual return value: "S-1-**4**-21-3477787073-812361429-1014394821"

Any idea how to fix this?  Do I need to pad the array out to 28, or even 32 bits?

Comment: Have you tried using [SecurityIdentifier Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.principal.securityidentifier?view=net-6.0) to convert the SID to a String ?

Comment: Also. [How to convert SID to String in .net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11580128/how-to-convert-sid-to-string-in-net)

Comment: *"It comes as a base64 encoded string."* - How are you retrieving it? I've never seen it returned as a base64 string. It's usually a byte array.

Comment: @GabrielLuci `DirectorySearcher()` then `JsonConvert.SerializeObject(ds.FindAll())`

Comment: @JayV **Zoiks!**  That did it (SecurityIdentifier class).  You should add that as an answer so I can accept it.  And THANKS!

Comment: @KirbyL.Wallace Glad to hear you got your answer. I won't add an answer as my other comment links to the answer I found when I had a similar question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As noted in the comments, the [`SecurityIdentifier`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.principal.securityidentifier) class makes this easy:

```
public static string Base64DecodeSID(string data) {

    var bytes = Convert.FromBase64String(data);
    
    var sid = new SecurityIdentifier(bytes, 0);
    
    return sid.Value;
}
```

You may want to add some error checks in there in case it's passed a bad value.

Calling `Base64DecodeSID("AQQAAAAAAAUVAAAAwdFKz9WmazDFb3Y8")` returns `S-1-5-21-3477787073-812361429-1014394821`